# How to Export Crystal Report to Excel using CrystalReport Object and TableAdapter?

Tags: c#, crystal-reports-2008

I am using TableAdapter method of dataset file to get data from database,
and Crysral report object to create report instead of CrystalReport file itself.
(Basically I don't want to use Physical CrystalReport File)

Here, sample of my Code

```
DataTable dtRpt = new DataTable();
CrystalReportViewer crv = new CrystalReportViewer();
using (uspRptComplainReceiptTableAdapter _adpSales = new uspRptComplainReceiptTableAdapter())
{
    dtRpt = _adpSales.GetData(Convert.ToByte(bolObj.CompId), bolObj.ComplainId) as DataTable;
    if (dtRpt != null && dtRpt.Rows.Count > 0)
    {
         crptComplainReceipt rpt1 = new crptComplainReceipt();
         rpt1.SetDataSource(dtRpt);
         crv.ReportSource = rpt1;
         crv.PrintReport();
    }
    else
         MessageBox.Show("Record not found.", "Report", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Now, I want to Export my report to Excel File using this method (CrystalReport Object).
Please, help me for this problem...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This:

```
 CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportClass rpt=new ReportClass();
 rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, "FilePath");
```

BTW do not forget to add the references.

Comment: Sorry, but i can't understand your answer..
what is cClass?? and where do i set my data source??

Comment: Sorry cClass was a mistype see my Update. `rpt` is instead of the physical crystal report file (as you called it). you have to make an object of the Report at first. then you will show your data and so on. when you want to export that you will call `ExportToDisk()` method in which there are two `parameters` the first is the format of the file you want your report to be converted to and the second is the `filepath` I've just written how to export your report to Excel (as your question is about that).

Comment: Yaaa.. it's working..
but, it's not need to declare ReportClass Onject.
only below line is enough for this
`rpt.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType.Excel, "FilePath");`